# Mysterious Seg fault

Tags: c, gdb

I'm getting a segfault I've seen before but have no idea how to solve. It's telling me that there's something wrong with strcpy, but I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone explain this message to me and what I need to do to fix it?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:60
60  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, this will show where the crash happens. It will also let you examine the function call stack and walk up it to your code, where you can examine variables to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is that supposed to be a joke?

Comment: @SwiftCore No, using the debugger is not a joke, you should really do it. (Well, how do you expect us to debug your program without any code shown? It's of course not `strcpy()` that fails but your code uses it improperly.)

Comment: Also, there are [many](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) [GDB](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/) [tutorials](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/), if you just [search](https://www.google.com/) a [little](http://www.bing.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compile your code with -g option,

```
gcc -g yourcode.c
```

should your program crash, this will generate a core dump (you may also need to activate core dump generation (eg `ulimit -c unlimited`)

now you can use gdb to trace the problem:

```
gdb -c core yourexecutable
```

use `bt` (backtrace) inside debugger to view stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Use a Debugger if you can or use a profiler if you can. If you can't do any of those spend time searching the code for strcpy(this could be in a DLL too) and check if it is being used correctly.